# Is combining python methods isupper and isnumeric/isdigits possible? What the heck am I not seeing in my list?

Tags: python, list, methods

I am learning python and as I complete my problems sets in each chapter I periodically go back to old ones and try to rewrite them with the new concepts I've learned:

My first question is whether or not I can combine isupper() and isnumeric() below?
I am trying to check a string to ensure that it contains only upper case characters and numbers. I have researched this before posting it here and the answers I've seen explain each method individually or the explanation is beyond my understanding thus far in my class and practice. I previously wrote the code below to solve the problem with a long conditional and now I am trying this. When I check the list compared to the individual print statements the list is not correct?

```
#code_str = "A12B44BP"
code_str = "a23736jtguyg4290267"
#code_str = "BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF"

 
x = len(code_str) % 4 == 0
y = "A1" in code_str
z = code_str is code_str.isnumeric() or code_str.isupper()

valid = [x == (len(code_str) % 4 == 0), 
        y == ("A1" in code_str), 
        z == (code_str is code_str.isnumeric() or code_str.isupper())]
        
if all(valid):
        print(True)
else:
        print(False)
 
        
#print(code_str[0])       
#print(valid)
#print(len(code_str) % 4)
#print(code_str.isnumeric())
#print(code_str.isupper())
```

Comment: You're not checking the individual characters to make sure they're upper case or numeric, you're checking whether the entire string is one or the other.

Comment: It's not clear why you are putting things like `y == ("A1" in code_str)` in the `valid` list. Since `y` is by definition equal to `"A1" in code_str` this will be true regardless of whether `"A1" in code_str` is true. It seems like you should have something like `valid = [x,y,x]`

Comment: This is a combination of using `is` where you meant to use `==` and the problem of thinking that `is`/`==` distributes over `or` (`a is b or c` is *not* the same as `a is b or a is c`).

Comment: @chepner Thank you!!!!!!!! The is and == helped.

Answer (score 0):

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex
>
> .isnumeric(): *Return True if **all characters in the string are numeric characters**, and there is at least one character, False otherwise.*
>
> .isupper(): Return True **if all cased characters in the string are uppercase** and there is at least one cased character, False otherwise.

You can try looping through the string and check each character instead.

```
code_str = "123ABC"

valid = True

# Check if every LETTER in the string is uppercase, 
# then check if every non-alphabetic character is a NUMBER
if not code_str.isupper():
    valid = False
else:
    for c in code_str:
        if not c.isalpha() and not c.isnumeric():
            valid = False
            break
      
print(valid)

#    Results:
#    code_str = "123"     # False
#    code_str = "123ABC"  # True
#    code_str = "123Abc"  # False
#    code_str = "!ABC123" # False
```

Comment: This makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to check a string to ensure that it contains only upper case characters and numbers

This can be done with a regex: `re.fullmatch(r"[A-Z\d]*/, s)`. `fullmatch` anchors the pattern to the front and the end of the string, `[A-Z\d]` specifies a character class containing anything in the uppercase character range (`A-Z`) or digits (`\d`).

Here's the usage on your test inputs:

```
>>> import re
>>> def all_upper_or_digit(s): return bool(re.fullmatch(r"[A-Z\d]*", s))
... 
>>> all_upper_or_digit("A12B44BP")
True
>>> all_upper_or_digit("a23736jtguyg4290267")
False
>>> all_upper_or_digit("BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF")
True
```

Another approach without regex is to create a generator expression which creates booleans matching your validation logic and pass it to `all`:

```
>>> def all_upper_or_digit(s):
...     return all(c.isdigit() or c.isupper() for c in s)
```

A few remarks on your code which I'm having a difficult time following:

- Write a function so you don't need to comment out different test strings.
- Try not to be fancy until you're sure you understand what logic you're implementing. You can write the logic with naive `for` loops and `if` conditions in rudimentary C-like code:

  ```
  >>> def all_upper_or_digit(s):
  ...     for c in s:
  ...         if not c.isupper() and not c.isdigit():
  ...             return False
  ...     return True
  ... 
  >>> all_upper_or_digit("A12B44BP")
  True
  >>> all_upper_or_digit("a23736jtguyg4290267")
  False
  >>> all_upper_or_digit("BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF")
  True
  ```
- Avoid conflating logic that makes sense to you in English with what Python accepts as logical: `code_str is code_str.isnumeric()` is nonsensical and always false because it tests whether a boolean (`code_str.isnumeric()` is the same object as `code_str` which we know is a string. There are other violations of what makes sense to Python throughout the code: `y == ("A1" in code_str)` when `y = "A1" in code_str` means you're comparing `"A1" in code_str == "A1" in code_str` which is a tautology.
- You have additional tests which weren't described in your validation specification:

  ```
  x = len(code_str) % 4 == 0
  y = "A1" in code_str
  ```

  but these are easy enough to add to the logic I've shown you, iteratively or with regex. I'll leave this as an exercise for the iterative versions, but for regex it'd be:

  ```
  re.fullmatch(r"(?=.*A1)(?:[A-Z\d]{4})*", s)
  ```

  which uses a lookahead to ensure the substring `"A1"` is somewhere within `s` and that the `[A-Z\d]` pattern occurs in chunks of 4.

Comment: thank you! This is a function I just wrote it outside of the function so I could test it individually to try to see what was not working. As far as regex I am not there in my class yet so that goes over my head but I completely understand what you mean with the function, for loop, and logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete function with the desired results. Clearly will keep practising !!!! Below the function is the original way I solved it before getting help trying this:

```
def valid_product_code(code_str):
    x = len(code_str) % 4 == 0
    y = "A1" in code_str
    z = code_str == code_str.isnumeric() or code_str.isupper()
    valid = [x, y, z]
    if all(valid):
                return(True)
    else:
                return(False)
    
    
     
    print(valid_product_code("A12B44BP"))
    print(valid_product_code("BFDSAUSA98932RWEFOEWA9FEAA1DSFSF"))
    print(valid_product_code("A1BBD5"))
    print(valid_product_code("BDD5664S"))
    print(valid_product_code("66aBSaA1fdsv"))       
    
    # def valid_product_code(code_str):
    #         if len(code_str) % 4 == 0 and "A1" in code_str and (code_str is code_str.isdecimal() or code_str.isupper()):
    #                 return True
    #         else:
    #                 return False
```